# Prove that there are infinitely many integer solutions to a diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Prove that there are infinitely many integer solutions to the diophantine equation: $(x-y)^7 = x^3y^3$

Comment: "infinite integer" $\: \mapsto \:$ "infinitely many integer" $\;\;\;$ ? $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:contest-math]?  If it's from a contest, please state the contest. :)  It's helpful in case some of us want to work more problems like this.

Comment: Will do that next time. Thanks for the reminder

Comment: Why only do it next time?  Why not do it now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $x=y+h$. Then it's equal:

$$h^7=y^3(y+h)^3$$

Now let's try $y=ah$, you have:

$$h^7=a^3h^3(a+1)^3h^3$$

It's equal:

$$h=a^3(a+1)^3$$

Now you can write down infinitely many integer which satisfies equation:

$$y=a^4(a+1)^3$$

$$x=a^4(a+1)^3+a^3(a+1)^3=a^3(a+1)^4$$

For $a \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Very intuitive approach. It looks like you may simplify the final answer for 'x'.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution: Let $x = \frac{k+1}{k} y$, then $$(x-y)^7=x^3 y^3 \Rightarrow \frac{y}{k^7}=\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^3$$

$$\Rightarrow y=k^4(k+1)^3,\qquad x=k^3(k+1)^4$$

Comment: What motivates making the construction in the first line?

Comment: Intuition and experiment. I noticed that $x=2y$ was a solution but that $x=3y$ or $x=4y$ was not. The next guess I tried was $x=(3/2)y$, then the general pattern.

Comment: That's brilliant!